# Display multiple images with links as a web part

Tags: 2010, web-part

I am running Sharepoint 2010 and i want to add a web part on the homepage with small thumbnail images with links to external websites.

I want the images to display in a grid 4x4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Content Editor Web Part and use basic HTML - Tables/Divs, etc

```
<table id="My4x4ImageGrid">
<tr>
    <td id="Col1Row1"><a href="url-01"><img src="image-01"></a></td>
    <td id="Col2Row1"><a href="url-02"><img src="image-02"></a></td>
    <td id="Col3Row1"><a href="url-03"><img src="image-03"></a></td>
    <td id="Col4Row1"><a href="url-04"><img src="image-04"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="Col1Row2"><a href="url-05"><img src="image-05"></a></td>
    <td id="Col2Row2"><a href="url-06"><img src="image-06"></a></td>
    <td id="Col3Row2"><a href="url-07"><img src="image-07"></a></td>
    <td id="Col4Row2"><a href="url-08"><img src="image-08"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="Col1Row3"><a href="url-09"><img src="image-09"></a></td>
    <td id="Col2Row3"><a href="url-10"><img src="image-10"></a></td>
    <td id="Col3Row3"><a href="url-11"><img src="image-11"></a></td>
    <td id="Col4Row3"><a href="url-12"><img src="image-12"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="Col1Row4"><a href="url-13"><img src="image-13"></a></td>
    <td id="Col2Row4"><a href="url-14"><img src="image-14"></a></td>
    <td id="Col3Row4"><a href="url-15"><img src="image-15"></a></td>
    <td id="Col4Row4"><a href="url-16"><img src="image-16"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is just displaying the the HTML code

Comment: Yes, thats what SharePoint is, HTML output. If it needs to be dynamic and actually requires code, then you should say so in the question. A 4x4 grid of clickable images is well suited to basic HTML.

Comment: so how would i add a HTML table to display as a table?

Comment: Answer edited to show HTML 4x4 grid with hyperlinked images

Comment: this is still just displaying the HTML Code

Comment: Add a Content Editor Web Part and click the [HTML] button, paste the code in there, not in the main WYSIWYG window.